# Comparing items in a list to a dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset (8,000 obs) and about 16 lists with anywhere from 120 to 2,000 items. Essentially, I want to check to see if any of the observations in the dataset match an item in a list. If there is a match, I want to include a variable indicating the match.

As an example, if I have data that look like this:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(1:10)
list1 <- c(2:4)
list2 <- c(7,8)
```

I want to end with a dataset that looks something like this

```
Obs  Var  List
1    1    
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
5    5    
6    6    
7    7    2
8    8    2
9    9    
10   10
```

How do I go about doing this? Thank you!

Comment: what if a value is found in more than one list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using boolean sum and `%in%`. If several match, then the last one is taken here:

```
dat <- data.frame(Obs = 1:10)
list_all <- list(c(2:4), c(7,8))
present <- sapply(1:length(list_all), function(n) dat$Obs %in% list_all[[n]]*n)
dat$List <- apply(present, 1, FUN = max)
dat$List[dat$List == 0] <- NA
dat


> dat
   Obs List
1    1   NA
2    2    1
3    3    1
4    4    1
5    5   NA
6    6   NA
7    7    2
8    8    2
9    9   NA
10  10   NA
```

Comment: OP has 16 lists

Comment: @ZahiroMor updated. Code for 16 is just expanding the code for 2. Here is a more general approach.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this right now and then update.